# Performance when building the Objective C application in the device

Tags: objective-c, device

I have a performance problem when I build the application in the Device. It is actually in my database. I have a table of wine details in which there are 2114 wine names. To get the all those wine names, I wrote this code in the `appDelegate`:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getWineDetails
{ 
   [wineDetailsList removeAllObjects];

   sqlite3_stmt* statement;
   const char *sql = "select *from wineDetails order by name";

   if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
   {
       NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
   }

   while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
   {
      primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
      //printf("\n primaryKey1 Value:%d",primaryKey);

      wineDetails *wineDets = [[wineDetails alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey database:database];    
      [wineDetailsList addObject:wineDets];

      //printf("\n ==========================%d",[wineDetailsList count]);
      [wineDets release];
   }

   sqlite3_finalize(statement);
   printf("\n Inside AppDelegate .....wineDetailsList count:%d",[wineDetailsList count]);
   return wineDetailsList;
```

}

I am calling this method in the `viewWillAppear` of another controller where I have to display the wine names in the table view.

The `viewWillAppear` code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CorkItAppDelegate* appDelegate = (CorkItAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    winesList = [appDelegate getWineDetails];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Here the problem is that when I build it in the device, it takes too much time to navigate into the controller due to the amount of date in the database. What should I do to get rid of this performance issue?

Thanks,

Monish Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick suggestion, you could add an index on the name column, that might speed up the fetch. Also, make sure you're not fetching any more things than you need.

Comment: Hi naven,

Actually I had no idea about the index in the database.

Comment: Yup I tried using index.even thought its slow...but it is faster than before not using index.